# Rcpp: Making a package from code containing a class

Tags: c++, rcpp

I am making an R-package using Rcpp. Here is a MWE showing my setup:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp ;

class A
{
private:
  std::map<int, int> m_map;

public:
  void fill_map(const size_t limit)
  {
    for(size_t i=0; i<limit; ++i)
    {
      m_map[i] = i;
    }
  }

  size_t size_map(){return m_map.size();}
};


// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<A> func1(const size_t limit)
{
  XPtr<A> ptr(new A(), true);
  return(ptr);
}
```

I can compile this using `sourceCpp` without errors. However, when I generate a package from this using RccpArmadillo (following this [tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/insong/www/pdf/rpackage_instructions.pdf)), I get the following error when compiling: `RcppExports.cpp:20:6: error: ‘A’ was not declared in this scope`

Why does the error appear and how can it be fixed?

---

Note: The tutorial works fine for creating packages when classes are not involved.

Comment: What is the host OS? Why isn't `size_t` qualified with `std::` - this can't compile if the code given is complete or unless `size_t` is redefined in `namespace Rcpp`. Take a close look at the error. Probably some other error is preventing `class A` from compiling successfully.

Comment: @iksemyonov I'm running Ubuntu 16.10. I wasn't aware that `size_t` needed to be qualified with `std::` (?) But it doesn't work either when I switch to `int` from `size_t`, so something tells me it is because of how I am treating the class in `Rcpp` and not a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Rcpp Attributes](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) vignette: You may need to create a file `mypackagename_types.h` with defines `A`. By convention, this *will be* included in the generated interface file, and with that your type `A` will be known.

A fairly simple examples is [Rblpapi_types.h](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/blob/master/src/Rblpapi_types.h) from our [Rblpapi](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi) package. You can see the header file being included [on line 4 of the interface file RcppExports.cpp](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/blob/master/src/RcppExports.cpp#L4).